# Where in the document to place javascript function definitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have placed all my javascript calls inside `jQuery.ready()` to ensure the DOM is fully loaded before accessing them. But for function definitions (ones that I wrote myself), what's the best practice in placing them (before their corresponding called of course). At the beginning of `<body>`? Or at the end of `<body>`? Or inside `jQuery.ready()`? Or it simply doesn't matter? Thanks.

Comment: _"before their corresponding called of course"_ - Actually, within the same script element or the same function scope your function declarations do not have to be before they are called because function declarations are "hoisted", that is, the JS interpreter treats them as if they were declared at the beginning of the block.

Comment: @nnnnnn - That's one piece of useful info there. As a newbie to js, I really appreciate knowledge like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not place functions inside the ready() function.

You should declare them above the ready call and ideally all of your js is handled at the bottom of the html.

Comment: Thanks. If it's just function **definitions**, what differences does it make if placing them at the top or bottom of the html?

Comment: Script elements are processed in document order. If your function declarations are in one script element and the code that calls them is in another, the declarations must be loaded when the functions are called.

Comment: @Kai Qing - Why not declare the functions inside the document.ready handler? If they're only called by each other and by other event handlers also setup within document.ready then that will work perfectly well with the advantage of keeping everything out of the global scope. Of course any functions that need to be called by code outside of the document.ready handler will also need to be declared outside. Maybe you have a good reason for saying not to do this, but how can we know unless you explain what it is...

Comment: @RobG - Thanks for your words. But I still want to see explanation to KaiQing's answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I say do not place them in the ready call simply for the sake of availability and in general the purpose of the ready function itself - execute this when the page is ready. You could argue that placement in header or footer is preference either way, but at the firm I work for we maintain the general standard that all js definitions and such are declared first then the last and final js before any analytical script is the ready call - stripped to only things relevant to that which is intended to be called when the html is rendered.

Comment: As for harm if placed in the ready call - it only affects things in a human way - like readability of code. So future programmers may assume and attempt to call a function declared in the ready function and be minorly inconvenienced to discover it there. I would liken it to something like declaring site config variables in a controller and not a config file. It may not matter at all, but it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your JavaScript in the head or top of the body, you will need to use jQuery ready **IF** they rely on some part of the DOM.  As a shortcut, you can just pass your code to `$`, like so:

```
$(function(){

  $("#domID").method();
});
```

However, you can forego this whole mess by putting your script at the bottom.  The browser reads your HTML top to bottom.  If the script that accesses `domID`, appears below the DOM element with id `domID` then it will work fine.  So the above code snippet can be further simplified via:

```
$("domID").method();
```

As a note, this is not always the case.  I have noticed you can not access canvas elements immediately.  It may be safer to use `$` or `$.ready`, then remove them as you become more comfortable with how the DOM and JavaScript are loaded.